# Return unique value in SQL when joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have question, I have hard time in solving a question on how to actually joining two table using inner join, where the return value shown must only be the unique value on both table.

For example: if table A contains:

```
ID       Name
-------------------
1        Andy
2        Anthony
3        Sandy
```

And table B:

```
ID       Job       
----------------------
1        Student
1        Entrepreneur
3        CEO
```

It will return only Sandy as CEO and not returning ANDY with both jobs as student and entrepreneur.

Thanks a lot for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3):

A simple join and aggregation would seem to work here:

```sql
SELECT a.ID, MAX(a.Name) AS Name, MAX(b.Job) AS Job
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

### Demo

The logic here is that the inner join filters off person in the A table not having any match at all in the B table.  For those which do have matches, we retain single job match only by checking the count.

Comment: Does it make sense to cut it to `HAVING COUNT(a.ID)=1`, avoiding checking the other fields - or will SQL engine be always smart enough to understand checking id is actually enough?

Comment: @raina77ow Semantically `COUNT(*)` feels right to me, because we just want a total record count of that particular `a.ID` group.  Yes, we could use your version as well, but `COUNT(*)` is also safe as it counts both null and non null.